# Version control "in the clouds"

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, saas

I'm a developer who works on both individual and group projects using Microsoft Visual Studio.  I could setup one of several different source control packages, such as VSS, SourceGear Vault or SVN on a server of my own and access them remotely; however, I don't want to deal with the hassle of setting it up, configuring it, etc.

Does anyone offer a hosted source control service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://unfuddle.com/ offers a wide variety of SCM offerings (Subversion/Git/Maybe CVS?) as well as issue tracking.  And they do it very well.

Comment: I've been using Unfuddle for a few months now and I really like the service!

Answer (score 7):

For Git, check out [GitHub](http://github.com). Good packages, used by an awful lot of opensource projects. Considered to be one of the best hosting experiences for git.

Answer (score 5):

I use [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com) to host all my personal projects. It has 500mb of storage and you can host your code and do bug tracking and issue tracking.

It also has a good set of tools and you can use SVN, Trac/SVN, Trac/git, Mercurial or even an external SVN server for source control.

Answer (score 3):

We use Dreamhost for our subversion repositories and are very happy so far, plus you can't beat the price:
http://www.dreamhost.com/hosting-features.html#svn

Answer (score 3):

Google Code, SourceForge all have code hosting solutions.  How private do you want to be ?

Answer (score 2):

A basic hosting plan at [dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/r.cgi?74720) gets you tons of web hosting space, bandwidth, database, jabber chat server, CVS, subversion repository and more for a little more than 5 bucks a month.

[Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) seems nice (SVN only), but i don't have any experience with it. Free plan has 20mb space for 3 users and 1 repository.

[Project Locker](http://www.projectlocker.com/) hosts both subversion repositories and an issue tracking software, trac, for you. Trac is real nice when coupled with version control.

Answer (score 1):

I used [CVSDude](http://cvsdude.com/) a long time ago. They were free up to 10 MBs at that time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using webfaction (webfaction.com) as my main web-host at the moment.  They offer subversion as a 'one-click-installer' - in reality it takes a few more clicks than the name suggests, but it's really a straightforward process.

Their technical support is absolutely brilliant, and you're provided with the same features across each of their levels of shared hosting.  I'd recommend them, most hosts I've used have been pretty awful in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Online, based on the capabilities of Team Foundation Server with additional cloud services, is the home for your project data in the cloud. Get up and running in minutes on our cloud infrastructure without having to install or configure a single server. Connect to your project in the cloud using your favorite development tool, such as Visual Studio, Eclipse or Xcode.

http://www.visualstudio.com/

Visual Studio Online Basic
Start your next development project in the cloud – 5 users are free!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Online is now [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs). You not only get cloud-hosted [version control](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/version-control-vs) with unlimited, free, private Git or TFVC repos, but also integrated bug and work item tracking with enterprise Agile tools for DevOps, like backlogs and Kanban boards, automation for build, test, and release plus other features for team collaboration and app development.

And your first 5 users are still free. Here's more about [how to get started with Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/sign-up-for-visual-studio-team-services).